# How to use system fonts with angular material?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to use system fonts using custom typography function. It doesn't seem to work properly. Or at the very least, I'm not sure how to test if I'm getting the desired font from the long list of fonts.

```
$custom-typography: mat-typography-config(
  $font-family:
    '-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,Oxygen-Sans,Ubuntu,Cantarell,"Helvetica Neue",sans-serif');
```

This shows up in developer tools as font family:

```
400 34px/40px -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,Oxygen-Sans,Ubuntu,Cantarell,"Helvetica Neue",sans-serif
```

Computed styles/font-family:

```
-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif.mat-display-1, .mat-typography .mat-display-1
```

I'm getting different font when I set the font-family on body {} css, instead of the mat-typography function.